# automatically get all sql table values

Tags: php, sql

I have a query which returns a row with over 20 values

```
TableTest

Country
User
Name
...
...
```

If I want to create an object in PHP for each value in the table how can I do that?

I currently do like this.

```
$generalValues = new stdClass();
$IdQuery = $this->m_queryFactory->getIdFromBuild($id, $pc);
$result = odbc_exec($this->m_connection, $IdQuery);
$no_results = odbc_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $no_results; $i++) {
    $Id = trim(odbc_result($result, "Id"));
    $query = $this->m_queryFactory->getQuery($Id);
    $result = odbc_exec($this->m_connection, $query);
    if (odbc_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        odbc_fetch_row($result);
    $generalValues->Country = odbc_result($result, "country");
    $generalValues->Name = odbc_result($result, "name");
    $generalValues->User = odbc_result($result, "user");
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

But how can I do it for every value in the table row whitout having to specify every table column value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` or simply `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` here  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = odbc_exec($this->m_connection, $query);
$generalValues = odbc_fetch_object($result);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-object.php